# MS SQL Server - concatenating in a particular way

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I've got a particular table that I need to concatenate using something like substring, but in a particular way. There are going to be lots of nulls but we still need to pay attention to them.

Basically, I've got something like...

```
PID         Date               Flag1            Flag2          Code
11          01/01/2014         1                0              16
11          25/12/2014         1                1              48
11          16/07/2016         0                1              9
12          07/01/2014                          0              16
12          08/01/2014         1                               
12          09/01/2014                                         16
13          01/10/2014         1                               4
13          01/11/2014         1                0              16
13          01/12/2014                          0              48
```

Would result in (very long)...

```
PID         Date                                  Flag1    Flag2    Code
11          01/01/2014,25/12/2014,16/07/2014,     1,1,0,   0,1,1,   16,48,9,
12          07/01/2014,08/01/2014,09/01/2014,     ,1,,     0,,,     16,,16,
13          01/10/2014,01/11/2014,01/12/2014,     1,1,,    ,0,0,    4,16,48,
```

This way, in some code I would use later, I would be able to tell which date each flag belongs to.

Any ideas? So far I've just been using the regular substring commands which do put things into the correct fields, but I can't tell what belongs with what.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PS2.PID, substring
                         ((SELECT        ',' + CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PS1.Date, 111) AS NVARCHAR) AS [text()]
                             FROM            dbo.PS PS1
                             WHERE        PS1.PID = PS2.PID
                             ORDER BY PS1.PID, PS1.Date FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 9999) + ',' [Date], substring
                         ((SELECT        ',' + LEFT(CAST(LUC.Code AS NVARCHAR), 2) AS [text()]
                             FROM            dbo.PS PS1 INNER JOIN
                                                      dbo.MyCodes LUC ON PS1.Code = LUC.Id
                             WHERE        PS1.PID = PS2.PID
                             ORDER BY PS1.PID, PS1.Date FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 9999) + ',' [Code], substring
                         ((SELECT        ',' + LEFT(CAST(PS1.Flag1 AS NVARCHAR), 1) AS [text()]
                             FROM            dbo.PS PS1
                             WHERE        PS1.PID = PS2.PID
                             ORDER BY PS1.PID, PS1.Date FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 9999) + ',' [Flag1], substring
                         ((SELECT        ',' + LEFT(CAST(PS1.Flag2 AS NVARCHAR), 1) AS [text()]
                             FROM            dbo.PS PS1
                             WHERE        PS1.PID = PS2.PID
                             ORDER BY PS1.PID, PS1.Date FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 9999) + ',' [Flag2]
FROM            dbo.PS PS2
```

Should also note, we will **always** have a Date. That will not be null. Same with the PID (as that's what they're grouped on).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I have used Date column as Edate so please replace that column and table name with your original one:

```
SELECT t1.PID, 
 STUFF(
    (SELECT ','  + cast(EDate AS varchar)
     FROM #tmpone t WHERE t.PID = t1.PID
    FOR XML PATH(''))
    , 1, 1, '') Edate,
 STUFF(
    (SELECT ','  + cast(Flag1 AS varchar)
     FROM #tmpone t WHERE t.PID = t1.PID
    FOR XML PATH(''))
    , 1, 1, '') Flag1,
 STUFF(
    (SELECT ','  + cast(Flag2 AS varchar)
     FROM #tmpone t WHERE t.PID = t1.PID
    FOR XML PATH(''))
    , 1, 1, '') Flag2,
 STUFF(
    (SELECT ','  + cast(Code AS varchar)
     FROM #tmpone t WHERE t.PID = t1.PID
    FOR XML PATH(''))
    , 1, 1, '') Code    
FROM #tmpone t1
GROUP BY t1.PID
```